# What should I do in Google Search Console if the URL for my domain changes completely?

Tags: google-search-console, google-index, migration

I was running a website called `https://example.com`. Multiple indexes are registered in the Search Console with the above domain.
As the content of the website changes, I need to reconfigure the indexed links.

### Breaking change

Is there a way to cleanly erase and restart the index associated with that domain?  I want to see only the index that will be used in the Search Console in a clean way.  I'd like it to look like the first time I registered a domain in Search Console.

I don't need the previous index because the contents of the website will be changed.  Should I make this change gradually rather than trying for a fresh start?

Comment: What does "Multiple indexes are registered in the Search Console" mean?  Google search console allows you to register properties, submit sitemaps, and view reports of indexed pages. Is one of those what you mean?

Comment: I'm talking about indexes associated with domains.

Comment: Are you talking about the search engine index?  There is typically just one index and it contains lots of domains.  Google can show you your index status for many pages, but it doesn't show you its full index in search console.

Comment: Yeah, right. I'm talking about the scope of index generation in the search console.

Comment: To add to my explanation, I'm going to postulate my situation
Previously, the index https://test.com/a was valid, but as the website changed, it became unnecessary, and there are several indexes that are affected. That's why I'm wondering if I can reset the domain index on the Google Search Console as if I had registered the domain for the first time. (or a smarter way)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are referring to as an "index" is more commonly referred to as a url.

If your site has new urls that you want Google to index, you can submit them one by one by clicking the "url inspection" link in the left menu (Console allows 10 inspections per day).

If you have many new urls you want indexed, you can submit a new sitemap that includes all the urls of your site (including new ones) by clicking the "sitemaps" link in the left menu.

For urls that no longer exist (like your example, test.com/) create a redirect for that url that points to a custom 404 page on your site. You can usually do this in your website admin console. You may also be able to create redirects directly on your web server.

You can also opt to do nothing with urls that no longer exist -- Google will stop attempting to crawl them once they can no longer be found. But Google prefers a 404 redirect, and a custom 404 page can help you direct your site users to other relevant pages on your site.